# Placing image which is in WebContent folder in H2 tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am creating tabbed sections with tab heading as H2 as below:

```
<div class="mainTab">
   <div class="myTab">
      <h2>Tab1</h2>
             Tab1 content here
   </div>
    <div class="mtTab">
       <h2>Tab2</h2>
             Tab2 content here
    </div>
<div>
```

I want to place a image before the tab heading. Like email image before Email tab heading.

This could be achieved by something like:

```
.h2one {
   font-size: 36px;
   font-weight: bold;
   background: url    ('http://images.findicons.com/files/icons/1676/primo/128/email_open.png') center left no-repeat;
padding-left: 120px;
 }

.h2two {
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
background: url('http://images.findicons.com/files/icons/1676/primo/128/email_close.png') center left no-repeat;
padding-left: 120px;
}
```

What if the images are in webcontent folder of my server. In that case how would the url look like. Will <=%request.getContextPath> work here ????

Comment: Here's a small jsfiddle doing what I imagine you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/NqXhB/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@nikunj; you can use `background-image` in your `h2` tag like this

```
h2{
 backgrond:url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 3px;
 padding-left:10px;
}
```

in above example i define image `background position` `left:0 & top:3px` but you can adjust your image according to your requirements & i also give `padding-left` so, text shift 10px and you can see the image.

you can also use `text-indent` instead of `padding`.

if you want separate image for different tabs then give different class for your `background images` like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/NqXhB/4/

Comment: if i need separate image for different tabs. How to achieve that with your answer ?

Comment: use classes. An h2 which needs a blue image (for example) will have class blue:

h2.blue{ background:url("image.png") no-repeat 0 3px; padding-left:10px;}

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the background image property of css.. here is a link that gets you started: http://w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background

and specifically to your question:

```
<h2 class="image">My photo album</h2>
```

and your style sheet is as follows:

```
 .image{ width: 300px; height: 75px; background-image: url(header.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

By W3 standards:

```
Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document
```

thus if your css is in content folder and you need to go to images folder.. you go something like this: url("../images/header.png")

Comment: i know.. well first link in google.. :P and its not like they have got everything wrong..

Comment: And what if I want different image for each tab. So I will have to define several image class specific to each header. Am i right ?

Comment: Ok I did it.. :D I knew I would have this coming at me when i was posting the answer.. I was planning to add a disclaimer..

Comment: And the w3c has a wiki too: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-image

Comment: Also, you can manually block sites in your google results. http://www.google.com/reviews/t?hl=en I've used it to block w3schools.

Comment: Guys.. one last doubt.... What if the images are in images folder of my webContent in the server. How would url be placed in that case ????

Comment: you can use relatve url from the source of css content.. thus if your css is in content folder and you need to go to images folder.. you go something like this: url("../images/header.png")

Answer (score 0):

you put image like this

```
<h2><img src='image/email.jpg' />Email</h2>
```